# SQl query to show the most popular category in terms of sales quantity for each country and each gender in year XXXX

Tags: mysql, sql

There are Three tables here Orders, Customers and Items.

```
create table Orders(order_id varchar(20), order_datetime datetime,
customer_id varchar(10), item_id varchar(20), amount int, quantity
int, age int);

insert into Orders values('a01' ,'2020-01-01 7:23:59', 'b27', 'c87',
20, 2 , 19);

insert into Orders values('a02', '2020-01-02 8:13:27', 'b33', 'c56',
100, 3, 15);

insert into Orders values('a02', '2020-01-02 8:13:27', 'b33', 'c57',
39,1, 15);

insert into Orders values('a03', '2020-01-02 13:26:39', 'b42', 'c31',
587,10, 19);


create table Customer(customer_id varchar(20), name varchar(20),
gender varchar(10), country varchar(20), age int);

insert into Customer values('b27' ,'sam', 'm', 'Singapore', 20);

insert into Customer values('b28' ,'bob', 'm', 'Indonesia', 27);

insert into Customer values('b29' ,'julie', 'f', 'Korea', 43);


create table Items(item_id varchar(20), category varchar(20));

insert into Items values('c87','sportswear');

insert into Items values('c56','skincare');

insert into Items values('c57','food');
```

Please tell me how to solve this. I have tried few combinations but were not successful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something? And what would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  Mysql 8 you have ROW_NUMBER to select the "best" from a PARTITION

> ```
> SELECT country,gender, category,oYear, total
> FROM
>   (SELECT country,gender, category,oYear, total,
>       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country,gender, category,oYear ORDER BY  total DESC) rn
>       FROM
>           (SELECT c.country,c.gender, SUM(o.amount * o.quantity) total, i.category,YEAR(o.order_datetime) oYear
>           FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Customer c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
>           INNER JOIN Items i ON o.item_id = i.item_id
>           GROUP BY  c.country,c.gender, i.category,YEAR(o.order_datetime)
>           ) t1 
>   ) t2
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```

> ```
> country   | gender | category   | oYear | total
> :-------- | :----- | :--------- | ----: | ----:
> Indonesia | m      | food       |  2020 |    39
> Indonesia | m      | skincare   |  2020 |   300
> Singapore | m      | sportswear |  2020 |    40
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e07d7f33e39f69a928cc064774413966)*

Comment: No need for ROW_NUMBER (), just longer code

Comment: When we are finding popular category, do we need to put category inside partition? I dont think so category should be present inside partition because it will calculate row_number for each category partition and we will not get partition which has highest sales. Let me know what do you think?